# Format date and validate

Tags: laravel

I have 2 small questions in Laravel. In fact, I would like to improve my application.

**First question:**

In my variable, "date_naissance", the format is `jj-mm-aaaa`when I create my recording on my form. I wish to replace `jj-mm-aaaa` with `__/__/__`

[image]

Is it possible to make this in laravel ?

```
<fieldset class="form-group {{ $errors->has('date_naissance') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
   <label for="form-group-input-1">Date naissance</label>
   <input type="date" name="date_naissance" id="date_naissance" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('date_naissance')}}"/>
 {!! $errors->first('date_naissance', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</fieldset>
```

**Second question:**

For the date of birth, is it possible of limite the year? 
For example, I want to avoid a date as 10/11/5000 or 01/01/1000

[image]
[image]

My Controller is the next:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
             'date_naissance' => 'required|date'          

        ]);

        Eleve::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('eleves.index')
                    ->with('success', 'save');
    }
```

Do you have an idea please?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your first question but for you 2nd question :

### How to validate birth date (validate between 2 dates in laravel)

Add **before** and **after** rules to validate between dates ,

```php
$request->validate([             
   'date_naissance' => 'required|date|before:today|after:1950'          
]);
```

In this example birth date should be between 1950 and today. Before and after value should be readable for [PHP strtotime](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function .

other Examples :

- before: **5 years ago**
- after: **last Monday**

Comment: thank you for your help. Concerning my first question, is it possible to replace 'jj-mm-aaaa' with '  -  -    '  or '__/__/__ ???